# Getting nth-child of a variable full of li tags

Tags: jquery

I've got a variable, let's call it $listObjects. The data of it is as followed....

```
<li>Data Here 1</li>
<li>Data Here 2</li>
<li>Data Here 3</li>
<li>Data Here 4</li>
```

I have tried every way I can think of, and can't find out how to get the nth-child of the list tags. Is this possible? I basically want to use nth-child(3n) on the $listObjects variable.

If the method above isn't possible, the $listObjects variable is being populated like so...

```
var $listObjects = $data.find('li[data-type=' + $filterType + ']');
```

Would it be possible to add the nth-child(3n) to that line?

Comment: Is `$listObjects` is a html string or array?

Comment: @AmarPalsapure My guess is it's a jQuery object

Comment: Correct, it is a jQuery object. Sorry, should have explained that better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

So this should do it:

```
$listObjects.filter(':nth-child(3n)')
```

If you don't need `$listObjects` for anything else then you could include the `:nth-child` in your original `find`:

```
$data.find('li[data-type=' + $filterType + ']:nth-child(3n)');
```

---

Let us clarify what's going on a little bit. Given this HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li data-id="a">One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li data-id="a">Three</li>
    <li data-id="a">Four</li>
    <li data-id="a">Five</li>
    <li data-id="a">Six</li>
    <li data-id="a">Seven</li>
</ul>
```

If we say `$('li[data-id]')` we'll get *One*, *Three*, *Four*, *Five*, *Six*, and *Seven* for the obvious reason.

If we say `$('li[data-id]').filter(':nth-child(3n)')`, we'll get *Three* and *Six* when you're probably expecting to get *Four* and *Seven*. What happens here? The `:nth-child` selector is being applied to all of the children of the `<ul>` rather than just those that match `[data-id]`. From the fine manual:

> The supplied selector is tested against each element; all elements matching the selector will be included in the result.

So this behavior matches the spec even if it is a little confusing and the spec could be more explicit on how things interact.

If we say `$('li[data-id]:nth-child(3n)')` then we get the (expected?) *Four* and *Seven*, i.e. every third element of `$('li[data-id]')`.

And finally, we can say this:

```
$.grep($('li[data-id]'), function(e, i) { return (i + 1) % 3 == 0 }));
```

​
Remember that `nth-child` is a CSS selector and thus 1-based, hence the `(i + 1)` in the test function. That will give us every third element again so we get *Four* and *Seven*. Note that [`$.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) gives you a plain array of DOM elements so you'll want to wrap that array in `$()` if you jQuery-ified version.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fw4xr/

---

**Summary**: `filter` may not be what you want but adding the `:nth-child(3n)` to the original selector probably is. Alternatively, you could use `$.grep` to grab the part of the `$listObjects` array that you're interested in. And the behavior of `filter` is a bit confusing.

Comment: Hmmmm, using $listObjects.filter seems to work, but it's almost like it is choosing the original nth-child set of 3 before the $data.find. In other words, there are 12 list objects in this $data. When using $data.find, it turns up 5 of them. When using addClass on the nth-child(3n) it adds it to the first, third and fifth. If you would like to see an example, see here http://www.joshdura.com/asteria/portfolio Click the Categories links. I am using console.log to log out the object.

Comment: @Josh: This stuff is a bit confusing and `filter` might not be what you're looking for. I've added some clarification.